# Fork() working incorrectly, returns 3 times

Tags: c, linux, bash, runtime-error, fork

I am designing a multi-threaded, multi-process application in C. The program is being tested in Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS with Linux kernel 2.6.31 and glibc version 2.11.1.

I am attempting to fork so that I can start bash as a child process to create a virtual shell. The problem is, sometimes fork() behaves very strangely by returning 3 times. As I understand it, fork() should return twice: once for the parent process and once for the child process. Unfortunately in my case, fork() returns 3 times: once for the parent process and TWICE for the child process. In htop the result looks like this http://i59.tinypic.com/20fdjci.png

[image: htop output]

In the image above PID 4320 is in the correct spot, but PID 4316 has been started as an orphaned process and is consuming all of the processor time.

Here is the code that produced that result:

```
#include "v_shell.h"

/*executes bash and attaches stdin and stdout to pipes*/
int vshell_init() {
    int rc;
    FILE * rf;

    /*initialize pipes*/
    //    mknod(STDIN_PIPE, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    //    mknod(STDOUT_PIPE, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    mkfifo(STDIN_PIPE, 0666);
    mkfifo(STDOUT_PIPE, 0666);

    pid_t result = fork();

    if (result == 0) { //this is the child
        prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "SHELL_INPUT", 0, 0, 0); //set name of the child process

        /*set thread priority*/
        int ret;
        struct sched_param params;
        params.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_RR) - 10;
        ret = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &params);
        if (ret != 0) {
            // Print the error
            record("Unsuccessful in setting thread realtime prio\n");
            return 0;
        }

        /*redirect standard input and output*/
        record("Redirecting stdin and stdout\n");

        rf = fopen(STDIN_PIPE, "r");
        if (rf == NULL) record("Error opening named pipe\n");
        rf = fopen(STDOUT_PIPE, "w");
        if (rf == NULL) record("Error opening named pipe\n");

        /*Close stdin and stdout to make sure*/
        rc = fclose(stdout);
        if (rc == EOF) record("Failed to close stdout\n");
        fclose(stdin);
        if (rc == EOF) record("Failed to close stdin\n");

        /*Copy stdin and stdout to named pipes*/
        rf = freopen(STDIN_PIPE, "r", stdin); //Redirect standard input
        if (rf == NULL) record("Failed to redirect stdin\n");
        rf = freopen(STDOUT_PIPE, "w", stdout); //Redirect standard output for new process
        if (rf == NULL) record("Failed to redirect stdout\n");
        rf = freopen(STDOUT_PIPE, "w", stderr); //Redirect standard error for new process
        if (rf == NULL) record("Failed to redirect stderr\n");

        record("Starting shell...\n");
        //Start shelld --  this one uses bash. the ./bashrc file should be used
        //        if (execlp("bash", "bash", "--noprofile", "--rcfile", "bashrc", "-i", (char *) 0) == -1) {
        if (execlp("bash", "bash", "--rcfile", "bashrc", "-i", "-s", (char *) 0) == -1) {
            record("ERROR in starting virtual shell!\n");
        }
        return -1; //shouldn't return if it worked correctly
    }

    return result;
}
```

Does anyone know what could make `fork()` produce this result?

Comment: Can you catch it with `strace`?

Comment: Unfortunately this problem is fairly intermittent, making it hard to debug. I haven't tried catching it with strace, let me see what I can find. Is there something I should look for?

Comment: Frankly, you aren't going to find `fork()` returning more than twice for any given call.  You'll need to add some logging to detect what's going on. You don't need to test the result of `execlp()`; if it returns, it failed.  Does `return -1;` ensure that the process exits?

Comment: I looked and `return -1` does not ensure that the process exits. I will change that. As for logging there is the line `record("Starting shell...\n");` that indicates if `execlp` is about to execute. This line prints twice if the error occurs. What other logging should I implement?

Comment: I don't understand why you claim one `fork()` call is returning thrice.  It cannot return more than once in any one process image, so the only way it could return thrice is if it forked two children instead of one.  I don't see any evidence of that.

Comment: Note, too, that process ID numbers normally increase over time until they wrap around.  If processes 4316 and 4320 are parent and child, in some order, then 4316 is almost surely the parent.  In that case, it must be going into death spiral mode some time after returning from `vshell_init()` (if that function is related at all).

Comment: You did say, however, that your program was *both* multithreaded and multiprocess.  Could it be that occasionally two threads call `vshell_init()` at nearly the same time?  If that happens then you probably end up with trouble because you'll use the same FIFO for both children.

Comment: And in that vein, why are you using `mkfifo()` in the first place?  If you just need a pipe for IPC then why not use `pipe()` instead?  That's what `pipe()` is *for*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger 
-Why I claim form is returning thrice: As far as I can tell the program does fork two children instead of one. Why does the evidence disprove this?
-Can two threads call `vshell_init()` at the same time? 'vshell_init()' is called before any of the other threads have been started.
-Why are you using `mkfifo()`I remember I started with `pipe()` but couldn't get it to work properly. I will try it this way again.

Comment: As far as the difference in PID goes, how do you know that 4320 and 4316 are not both children?

Comment: Naturally I cannot disprove that one `fork()` call spawns two child processes in your case.  The evidence you have presented is inconclusive.  However, I find it far more *credible* that `fork()` in fact behaves as documented, and as it has always been observed to behave for everyone else.

Comment: this variable 'rf' is being used for several different pipes,  this loses the original file descriptor for each file.

Comment: this line: if (rc == EOF) record("Failed to close stdin\n"); is using the results of the fclose(stdout) because the line fclose(stdin) is not saving the returned value into rc

Comment: as I see it,  the one process is consuming (almost) all the CPU time because its' priority was set very near the max value\

Comment: freopen() is expecting a currently open file descriptor and the file descriptor being passed is NOT currently open.

Comment: this line: rf = freopen(STDOUT_PIPE, "w", stderr); opening the wrong item.  it should be opening STDERR_PIPE, which the code fails to define.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the png as if one process has reparented itself to `init` (normally meaning its parent has died), but is not a zombie.

Two possible explanations:

1. You are calling `vshell_init` more than once. I'm betting you would have caught that one though.
2. (more likely) the `bash` shell is *itself* forking. Bash forks more than you might think (for example a script with things in `()` will fork).

To debug

```
strace -f -s2048 -o trace.out yourprogramnamehere
```

then search for `execlp` and see what's happening.

If this is intermittent, you might want to find out what on earth 4316 is doing, e.g.:

```
strace -f -s2048 -o trace.out -p 4316
```

When `fork()`-ing, make sure you close all the FDs you aren't passing through (here's an example which closes all but one pipe)

```
{
  int i;
  char *devnull = "/dev/null";
  ....
  for (i = getdtablesize () - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      if (!pipedata || (i != pipefd[0]))
        close (i);
    }

  i = open (devnull, O_RDWR);
  if (i == -1)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open /dev/null\n");
      _exit (1);
    }

  if (pipedata)
    {
      dup2 (pipefd[0], 0);
    }
  else
    {
      i = open (devnull, O_RDONLY);
      if (i != 0)
        {
          dup2 (i, 0);
          close (i);
        }
    }

  i = open (devnull, O_WRONLY);
  if (i != 1)
    {
      dup2 (i, 1);
      close (i);
    }

  i = open (devnull, O_WRONLY);
  if (i != 2)
    {
      dup2 (i, 2);
      close (i);
    }
  ...
}
```

And set up your signal masks in a way `bash` will understand:

```
{
  ...
  sigset_t set;
  struct sigaction sa;
  ...
  /* Set up the structure to specify the new action. */
  memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (struct sigaction));
  sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
  sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction (SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGPIPE, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);

  /* unblock all signals */
  sigfillset (&set);
  pthread_sigmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am running strace now to see if I can get it to make the same error. In the meantime, I am fairly sure that bash is not doing any forking because the ' record("Starting shell...\n");' line prints twice. This seems to indicate that the code for the child process is running twice for some reason.

Comment: @user2304905 : the other explanation for that printing twice that you might like to eliminate is that the `vshell_init` function is being called twice. How about putting a log line immediately before the `fork()` and see if the number of such log lines captured matches with the number of 'Starting shell' logs. Sometimes it's the silliest things ...

Comment: The fact that it is an intermittent problem makes me think its not a problem with my code, but a problem with the way it is interacting with linux. Upon running the program several times trying to get it to fail I noticed that Bash DOES fork while it is starting up, but then goes back to one process after it has finished starting. Is this expected operation? Could the bashrc file I am using be the culprit?

Comment: I would expect `bash` to fork when running a script. The question is more why the process is being left around. I notice you aren't closing FDs that your parent process uses (which are going to be passed to `bash` to get confused about), nor are you sanitising signal settings. You might try that. I've amended the answer with some code snippets.